# How to reduce committed Apache memory?

Tags: apache-2.2, memory-usage

Update 24th Oct

Dump of ps axl as requested by @David Schwartz : http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=z8riS

---

During busy periods we hit Apache max connections (currently set to 256). I'd like to increase the max connections setting, but have been advised not to, due to our memory being over-committed during these periods. However, the actual RAM usage doesn't seem to be anywhere near the committed value.

How is the committed value calculated for Apache processes? And how can I reduce this?

I have already tried setting the PHP memory_limit to a lower value, but this has had no effect on the committed value in my munin graphs:

[image]

Server specs:

- DELL PowerEdge 2950 MKIII
- 8 GB RAM
- Single Socket Quad Core Intel Xeon 5320 LV 1.86GHz
- 2 x 146GB SFF 10K RPM Drive in RAID 1
- Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
- PHP 5.3.3

The server is dedicated to Apache (MySQL is on another box).

Comment: The committed memory is just a warning -- it's the maximum amount of physical memory that might be needed if every process actually uses all the memory it has 'reserved'. Getting it down wouldn't help you as it would just mean you wouldn't be getting a valid warning. You're basically asking how to silence that annoying smoke detector. You should be trying to figure out what's burning -- if anything.

Comment: Hi David. Yes, agreed. So how would I figure out what's burning?

Comment: I would start by getting a `ps axl` output from a time when the committed memory level is high. See what processes have a high RSS, if any.

Comment: @David Schwartz it's a fairly big amount of text: http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=z8riS plenty of httpd processes (probably expected...)

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to separate serving of PHP scripts and static files.

You can serve static files very efficiently with `worker MPM` and even better with `event MPM` available for `httpd 2.4+`. But you can not use this MPM for serving PHP scripts, as PHP isn't thread-safe.

For PHP you can run a separate httpd instance (I'm running it on my server with `Listen 127.0.0.2:488`) and configure main server as a reverse proxy:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond /var/www/html%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://127.0.0.2:488/$1 [P,L]
```

With `mod_remoteip` (again - available from httpd 2.4) it would be truly transparent for a PHP script.

Or use for example [php-fpm](http://php-fpm.org/).

This way request for static files, HTTP persistent connections etc. will use a fraction of RAM.

Comment: This answer is a copy of [my answer to another question](http://serverfault.com/a/423306/1806) but that question got closed.